# Printing from C#

Tags: c#, printing

I need to print to different positions on an A4 paper from C#. What are my options for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the objects/methods of the System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument class should get you going in the right direction.

Here is a link to an example: [C# Printing Functions - O'Reilly media](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/06/24/printing.html)

Comment: Would this be easier than using the Open XML Format SDK to create a word doc that is printed?

Comment: @Danny: I've never used the Open XML Format SDK so I really couldn't say. I had a little trouble with the PrintDocument class at first but after some "getting used to" I'm pretty well used to it now.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use the Printing functions that c# provide you can use crystal report and design your page as you like and then print it.